# Is it possible to data bind a combo box and a text box between them?

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

Let's say you have a combobox and a textbox.

The combo box contains a list of items and I would want to bind the textbox "text" property to the current combobox selection.

In WPF this could be done but I've not found a way in WinForms.

Is there a way or is WinForms too limited?

Notes:

- I know I could use WPF instead, but the project is already in WinForms and rewriting it is out of the question.
- I'm asking about a combobox and textbox but this could be any other combinations.
- I'm looking for a way to do it from design time it at all possible.

Comment: If you databind them both to the same object (implementing the right observable interfaces), then change notifications should cause the value to be propagated automatically to the object and thence to the other control, with no additional code required.

Comment: @Ben, although there is a data binding capability in WinForms, it is not half as comfortable as WPF. I would prefer just the same solution as Machinegon's suggestion.

Comment: @BenVoigt: you don't need an intermediate object. I thought I might need to use an intermediate object (sort of an internal DTO), but what would be the point in that when a simple event would suffice? I was able to figure out a combination of properties to use for a `Binding` object to work.

Comment: @IAbstract: Because an intermediate object can be wired up using the Forms Designer, which the question requested.  I myself prefer an event, but that does require code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can bind the text box to the item (`Text`) selected in a combo box:

```
   public partial class Form1 : Form {
      Binding binding;

      public Form1() {
         InitializeComponent();

         binding = new Binding("Text", comboBox1, "Text");
         textBox1.DataBindings.Add(binding);
      }
   }
```

Comment: I think in answer to one of your question: *I'm looking for a way to do it from design time it at all possible* ...without writing your own controls which add some designer support, it may not be possible. WinForms has limitations.

Comment: I'm accepting your answer since it is closer to what is feasible with the technology.

Answer (score 2):

You could Add an onSelectedIndexChange event handler on the combo box and modify the textbox form there.

Comment: This would be my way. Unlike in WPF, the ability to just "bind" one GUI control to another isn't built-in; you have to hook into event handlers to get the job done. Still very possible.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go: These lines creates a delegate, whose begin called whether the selected index has been changed under the item. Afterwards it sets the textboxs, text property to the selected items text from the combobox :)

```
            TextBox txtbox = new TextBox();
            ComboBox cob = new ComboBox();
            cob.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(delegate(object sender, EventArgs e) { if (cob.SelectedIndex > -1) txtbox.Text = cob.Items[cob.SelectedIndex].ToString(); });
```

Comment: This will cause an exception when no item is selected.